# Two simple cases of quantifier elimination for Heyting algebras

Tags: lo.logic, intuitionism

*This extracts a simple case from a [cross-post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131366/127575) at cs.SE.*

Here is a fact about Intuitionistic Propositional Logic:

> A formula $p$ is equivalent to a formula of the form $q \lor \neg q$ if and only if $\neg p$ is false.

This can be reformulated in algebraic semantics:

> For any Heyting algebra $H$ and any element $p\in H$, there exists a $q\in H$ with $p=q\lor\neg q$ if and only if $\neg p=\bot$ (the bottom element of $H$).

This eliminates an existential quantifier, in the sense of finding an equivalent condition on $p$ which does not involve any "there exists" statement.

This leads to the question that interests me:

> Given a pair of elements $p,p'$ in a Heyting algebra $H$, when can they be written as $p=q\lor\neg q$ and $p'=q'\lor\neg q'$ with $q\land q'=\bot$?

Is it possible to eliminate existential quantifiers here too?

**Much later -- update:** a still simpler similar question which I also do not know anything about.

Can one eliminate the existential quantifier from the following formula (in the language of Heyting algebras):
$$
\exists x\ p = (q\land x)\lor\neg(q\land x)
$$

Comment: Sorry! I gave an incorrect answer, and deleted it. Still, this means that I will upvote the question (I thought it was simple...).

Comment: So we're looking for something like "$\neg \neg p$ and $\neg \neg q$ and ..."?

Comment: Yes... but I wonder if it's possible. An example I believe to be revealing is this: $p = r\vee \neg r$ and $p'= \neg r\vee \neg\neg r$. We can then take $q=r, q'=\neg r$. Still, neither $p$ or $p'$ is a theorem in IPL, so that particular simplification that I had in mind does not always hold... perhaps some other simplification is possible.

Comment: @MattF. I've highlighted the question, and also tried to make it more precise, is it better now?

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk Great observation! This also relates to another instance of the same question which I decided to omit here: whether one can characterize those $p$ of the form $\neg r\lor\neg\neg r$. This is definitely more restrictive than just $\neg\neg p$: for example, in the duality semantics $\neg\neg p$ means that the corresponding up-set of the dual space contains the whole maximum of the dual space, while if $p$ is $\neg r\lor\neg\neg r$ then in addition this up-set must contain all those points which see unique maximal point.

Comment: @MattF. Excellent, thank you very much! This is WAY clearer than what I wrote!

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk Accordingly, here is an example when neither $p$ nor $p'$ has form $\neg r\lor\neg\neg r$. Consider the algebra of up-sets of the poset $x<X>0<X'>x'$, and let $p=\{X,X',x'\}$, $p'=\{x,X,X'\}$. They satisfy the requirement with $q=\{X\}$ and $q'=\{X'\}$. However the only two up-sets of the form $\neg r\lor\neg\neg r$ are the whole poset and the whole poset except $0$.

Comment: @MattF. Just noticed that you also changed the title. While yours is more clear, I think it is sort of misleading. However I must admit I don't see how to improve it further...

Comment: In the question, do we have to say "$\neg p$ leads to contradiction" instead of just "$\neg p$ is false"? And as long as I am whining, the "provably" is vacuous, it should go.

Comment: While I agree that the body is improved, I think the original title was clearer.

Comment: @MattF. Tried another title, please have a look

Comment: @AndrejBauer That's more adequate, thanks